# Codeblocks macros

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I want to print a string generated by the preprocessor:

```
cout << GITHASH << endl;
```

It works very well building the application from the command line:

```
g++ -DGITHASH="\"dirty\"" app.cpp -o app.o
```

But if I put this macro to codeblocks's compiler define setting in the project build options, I get following error:

> Error: »dirty« was not defined in this scope

[image: project build options]

Does anyone know how to define this macro correctly in codeblocks settings?

I use codeblocks 16.01 on ubuntu 16.04.

**Edit:**
Now I want to replace "dirty" with git description of my project.

```
GITHASH=\\"$(shell git describe --dirty --always --tags)\\"
```

Any idea?

**Edit:**

It works with:

```
GITHASH=\\"`git describe --dirty --always --tags`\\"
```

Comment: It is working perfectly fine on my system, win 10 with codeblocks 16.01

Comment: Have you tried GITHASH=\\"dirty\\"

Comment: @user3161880 thank you, it works!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that

`GITHASH="\"dirty\""`

is written exactly as it is, there should be no space before or after =  (the equals sign).

Alternatively, try writing `GITHASH=\"dirty\"` or `GITHASH=\\"dirty\\"`